# Dynamically counting objects in an aggregate Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-orm

I have a relatively complex query to handle and I'm bashing my head against it.

Allow me to explain the scenario.

I want to return a queryset annotated with the number of cases a `user` has completed where they are certified.

Imagine my user has three roles. `a_delegate`, `b_certified` and `c_accredited`.

- `a_delegate` tells us that the `user` is in training for course `a`,
  we don't want to count any completed cases for course `a`.
- `b_certified` tells us that the `user` has completed training for course `b` and is certified. We need to count these completed cases
- `c_accredited` tells us that the `user` has advanced past their training for course `b`. We need to count these completed cases

I am using the built-in `User` model that Django supplies, nothing special there. Roles are just the name of the built-in `Group` model that Django supplies again.

Now, I know this is likely to get "just write raw sql" comments, and that's fine. I'm not dismissing the possibility of using raw sql here. I just want to know if there is a way of doing this with the ORM first.

I have this function, which maps input to the relevant roles.

```py
def convert_filter_str(str: str) -> Tuple:
    """
    Converts expected filters into course names and returns them
    and the relevant roles as a Tuple
    """

    APPLIANCES: Dict = {
        'a': 'Type A',
        'b': 'Type B',
        'c': 'Type C',
    }

    ROLES: Dict = {
        'a': ['a_certified', 'a_accredited'],
        'b': ['b_certified', 'b_accredited'],
        'c': ['c_certified', 'c_accredited'],
    }

    filters: List = str.split(',')
    converted_filters: List = []
    converted_roles: List = []

    for filter in filters:
        filter = filter.strip()
        converted_item = APPLIANCES[filter]
        converted_role = ROLES[filter]
        converted_filters.append(converted_item)
        converted_roles.append(converted_role)

    return converted_filters, converted_roles
```

So, if the user has input the filter as `a,b` then:

- `converted_filters` should return `['Type A', 'Type B']`
- `converted_roles` should return `[['a_certified', 'a_accredited'], ['b_certified', 'b_accredited']]`

If we consider what I mentioned earlier, `User` has three roles. `a_delegate`, `b_certified` and `c_accredited` so according to the filters above, we should only be looking at returning the count for cases for `Type B`.

For brevity I already have a Queryset with this user in it.

I need to filter this dependant on the input of the user so the more filters they apply the more counts are added.

I thought of using Sum, with a list of count aggregates within, but that throws `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Count'`

```py
final_qs: User = user.annotate(
    completed_cases=(Sum(
        [Count(
            'patientcase',
            filter=Q(
                groups__name__in=role_filter[i]
            )
        ) for i in range(len(role_filter))],
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
)
```

I also thought of using Sum, with a generator of count aggregates within, but that throws `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'generator'`

```py
final_qs: User = user.annotate(
    completed_cases=(Sum(
        (Count(
            'patientcase',
            filter=Q(
                groups__name__in=role_filter[i]
            )
        ) for i in range(len(role_filter))),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
)
```

Is there a way to make this work via the ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I have come to creates an expression that can then be passed to annotate.

```py
def build_filtered_count(appliance_filter, role_filter):
    """
    Dynamically builds count exprerssions based on the filters
    passed to the function
    """

    counts = [Count(
        'patientcase',
        filter=Q(
            groups__name__in=role_filter[i]
        ), distinct=True
    ) for i in range(len(role_filter))]

    return sum(counts)
```